# Avalonia remove the animation (effect) of pressing the button

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I have a question about Avalonia UI, it is necessary to remove the animation (effect) of pressing the button.

I tried to find suitable documentation and similar questions, but I did not find an answer, what ChatGPT gives does not work.

How can this be done preferably by code C#

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry it took so long for you to get an answer.  Here is how to remove the little size transform on the buttons when pressed.

```xml
<Style Selector=":is(Button):pressed">
  <Setter Property="RenderTransform" Value="none" />
</Style>
```

This will remove it from all buttons but you can alter the selector to target specific ones.